# Java format double with performance

Tags: java, performance

I have the need to format decimal value upto 6 decimal points. I can easily achieve the same by decimal formatting using

```
private static DecimalFormat df2 = new DecimalFormat(".######");
double input = 32.123456;
System.out.println("double : " + input);
System.out.println("double : " + df2.format(input));'
```

but my data volume is quite high its in millions is their any better way to achieve the same with high performace. Any helpful link will also work.

Comment: You could keep all your values as `long` with the understanding that the actual value is `val / 100000`, then format an integer and insert a `.` six places from the right.  I don't know whether that would really be faster.  In 1980 I'd say it would definitely be faster, but floating-point processing performance has improved significantly.  I think the only answer is to try a few things and profile them.

Comment: [link] (http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2000/12/15/formatting_doubles.html) Did you check it?

Comment: yes i have already checked that link

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save memory then use float data type instead of double. The float data type is a single-precision 32-bit IEEE 754 floating point.